# What tactic should I use to derive a contradiction from an absurd equality?

Tags: equality, coq, coq-tactic

Let's say that I have `H: 0 = 1` in scope. How can I use this to conclude `False`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the tactic [`discriminate`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic90).

Comment: Or `ediscriminate` / `congruence` / `inversion <hyp>` / `easy`. It depends on  what one is trying to achieve.